# Antlr4 grammar extraneous input with single space

Tags: antlr4

I'm having an issue with whitespace in my grammar.

Here is a minimal grammar which still has the issue:

```
sourceUnit
  : ( foo ) EOF ;

foo
  : (Identifier ':' Identifier)
  ;

StringLiteral
  : '"' DoubleQuotedStringCharacter* '"'
  ;

DoubleQuotedStringCharacter
  : ~["\r\n\\] | ('\\') ;  // The problem is in here somewhere

Identifier
  : [a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z0-9$_]* ;

WS
  : [ \t\r\n]+
    -> skip;
```

If I test this grammar with the following input:

```
aaa: bbb
```

I get `extraneous input ' ' expecting Identifier`. If I add a space between the Identifiers:

```
aaa:  bbb
```

It parses without a problem. If I remove the `~` in `DoubleQuotedStringCharacter` it works, but I'm not sure why, and the grammar is not valid without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Declare `DoubleQuotedStringCharacter` as a `fragment`.

The lexer works by going through your lexical rules and seeing which one matches on the current input. Of those rules that match, it then takes the one that produces the longest match - in case of a tie, it picks the rule that comes first in the grammar. Once it picked a rule, it then produces a token of the given type to be used by the parser and then applies the same logic with the remaining input¹.

With that in mind, here's how your lexer handles the input `"aaa: bbb"`:

1. - Current input `"aaa: bbb"`.
   - Applicable rules: Identifier (matches `"aaa"`), DoubleQuotedStringCharacter (matches `"a"`?)
   - Pick: Identifier because it's the longer match
2. - Current input `": bbb"`.
   - Applicable rules: ':' (matches `":"`), DoubleQuotedStringCharacter (also matches `":"`)
   - Pick: ':' because both matches are the same and string literals have higher priority than named rules
3. - Current input `" bbb"`.
   - Applicable rules: WS (matches `" "`), DoubleQuotedStringCharacter (also matches `" "`)
   - Pick: DoubleQuotedStringCharacter because both matches are the same and DoubleQuotedStringCharacter comes first in the grammar
4. Same as 1
5. EOF

Now for the input `"aaa:  bbb"` it looks almost the same except that step 3 now becomes:

- Current input `"  bbb"`.
- Applicable rules: WS (matches `"  "`), DoubleQuotedStringCharacter (matches `" "`)
- Pick: WS because it's the longer match

So this time WS wins because of the longest-match rule.

You could make WS win out in both cases by moving `DoubleQuotedStringCharacter` to the end of the grammar, so that all other rules will have priority over it, but that's not the proper solution.

The important thing to realize is that you never want a `DoubleQuotedStringCharacter` token to be generated at all. You want to use `DoubleQuotedStringCharacter` as a part of other definitions (namely `StringLiteral`) and never on its own. That's what fragments are for. If you declare `DoubleQuotedStringCharacter` as a fragment (using the `fragment` keyword), you'll be able to use it inside lexical rules, but it will not be seen as a lexical rule of its own, so it won't be considered when deciding which lexical rule to apply.

---

¹ This happens lazily as tokens are requested by the parser, but that doesn't really matter for the purposes of this answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for a clear and thorough answer!